# Angular - Undefined property when using *ngfor, (change)

Tags: html, angular, function, typescript, parameters

I want to **insert a text from an object into an input area** (which is PrimeNG's editor, and works like a textarea) **after the user selects an option from the select area**.

As you can see on the `(change)` on `<select>` element, I am sending two elements, the first element works just fine, but the second one is going as `undefined` and I am not sure why!

I have tried defining that element using #, but it does not work either. I have googled and read a lot a bout it but I can't find a way to read that element. Thanks for your time!

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let disparaEmail of listaAvisos; let i=index" [formGroup]="disparaEmail" class="ui-g-4" style="margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-radius: 5px; min-width: 466.828px;">

       <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700" style="padding-top: 10px;">Tipo de Aviso:</p>
           <select class="fw500 font1 inputtb" formControlName="fkTipAvi" [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.selTipAvi" (change)="atualizaEditor(disparaEmail.selTipAvi, disparaEmail.selMsgTipo)">
               <option value="">---Selecione---</option>
               <option *ngFor="let tipAvi of listaTipoAviso" value="{{tipAvi.id}}">
                 {{tipAvi.assuntoPd}}
               </option>
           </select>

       <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700" style="padding-top: 10px;">Mensagem:</p>
       <p-editor [style]="{'height':'300px'}" formControlName="msgTipo" [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.selMsgTipo" required> </p-editor>

 </div>
```

TS:

```
constructor(
//...
){
    this.listaTipoAviso = new Array<TipoAviso>();
        this.tipoAvisoService.listarTipoAvisos().then((data: any) => {
           //Feeding this element
        }
    })
}

atualizaEditor(selTip, editorMsg){
    let procuraLista = this.listaTipoAviso;
    procuraLista = procuraLista.filter(item=>
    Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k] != null && 
        item[k].toString().toLowerCase()
        .includes(selTip))
    );
    console.log("Value: " + procuraLista[0].msgPd + ". Editor: " + editorMsg);

    editorMsg = procuraLista[0].msgPd;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried just sending `disparaEmail`, and calling `console.log(disparaEmail)` to see what properties are defined?

Comment: @user184994 I have sent only `disparaEmail` and checked on `console.log`. It only shows me the id I am searching on `{{tipAvi.assuntoPd}}`, and I won't ever have `disparaEmail.selMsgTipo` I want. How am I supposed to send such parameter to the function?

Comment: @SunilSingh Sorry! What do you mean as 'feel the content'?

Comment: It was typo, I meant Did you fill the content in `p-editor` which has the ngModel disparaEmail.selMsgTipo ?

Comment: @SunilSingh I did, by doing `this.msgEmail = procuraLista[0].msgPd;` it inserts the string I want into every element of `disparaEmail`, but I want it to be inserted only on the element that was selected the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me re-iterate your question.

You have select box which has the list of complex object. Object the has the properties `selTipAvi` and `selMsgTipo` etc. Now whenever user select the any option from select box, the `selMsgTipo` property of selected item will be displayed in `p-editor` and user can edit if he wants.

To achieve the above scenario we can simplify your code as -

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let disparaEmail of listaAvisos; let i=index" class="ui-g-4" style="margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-radius: 5px; min-width: 466.828px;">

       <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700" style="padding-top: 10px;">Tipo de Aviso:</p>
           <select class="fw500 font1 inputtb" [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.selTipAvi" #selectEmail (change)="selectedEmail = selectEmail.value ">
               <option value="">---Selecione---</option>
               <option *ngFor="let tipAvi of listaTipoAviso" [value]="tipAvi">
                 {{tipAvi.assuntoPd}}
               </option>
           </select>

       <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700" style="padding-top: 10px;">Mensagem:</p>
       <p-editor *ngIf="selectedEmail" [style]="{'height':'300px'}" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmail.selMsgTipo" required> </p-editor>

 </div>
```

I have removed the ngForm for now since [(ngModel)] is being used. We used either go with reactive or ngModel way.

### ts

```
constructor(
//...
){
    this.listaTipoAviso = new Array<TipoAviso>();
        this.tipoAvisoService.listarTipoAvisos().then((data: any) => {
           //Feeding this element
        }
    })
}

selectedEmail = {};
```

> Note : code was written directly in stackoverflow editor so there could be some typo or syntetical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: I have adapted your answer with the situation I got (I have forgot to insert some details about the object) but I have managed to make it work now, MUCH obliged for your help my friend!